# How to Listen two separate buttons in Java AWT?

Tags: java, button, awt, actionlistener

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
//1st step  
public class ActionListenerExample implements ActionListener{  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Frame f=new Frame("ActionListener Example");  
    final TextField tf=new TextField();  
    tf.setBounds(50,50, 150,20);  
    Button b=new Button("Click Here");  
    b.setBounds(50,100,60,30);  
    //2nd step  
    b.addActionListener(this);  
    f.add(b);f.add(tf);  
    f.setSize(400,400);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);   
}  
//3rd step  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            tf.setText("Welcome to Javatpoint.");  
}  
}
```

In the above I want to add another button and add ActionListener and define `actionPerformed` method but that method needs to print just hello in terminal.

What Will I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful.

Mainly it's needed to add separate listeners for each button.(same listener could be used also but then need to filter from where is coming the event in order to perform different for each button)
 Also it's updated for close event. But better try to look on `JFrame(Swing)` since `Frame` is quite ancient. Anyway main principles are the same.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ALTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame f = new Frame("ActionListener Example");
        final TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 20);
        Button b = new Button("Button_1");
        b.setBounds(50, 100, 60, 30);
        Button b2 = new Button("Button_2");
        b2.setBounds(150, 100, 60, 30);

        f.add(b);
        f.add(b2);

        ActionListener al_1 = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tf.setText("B1 : " + e.getActionCommand());

            }
        };

        ActionListener al_2 = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tf.setText("B2 : " + e.getActionCommand());

            }
        };
        b.addActionListener(al_1);
        b2.addActionListener(al_2);
        f.add(tf);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        // close frame
        f.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

For console output, just update `al_2` with `System.out...` instead of `tf TextField`